# Cannot set custom timeout on JAX-WS Eclipse generated client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, websphere

I have an existing WSDL and from that used eclipse version 4.5 to generate a client.  This gives me a code generated proxy provider.  I have tried the following with no success (by the way im using java 7.079):

```
this.webservice = new ENC3WebAppServicePortProxy(username, password);
Descriptor desc = webservice._getDescriptor();
desc.setEndpoint(webserviceURL);

// Set timeout
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) webservice._getDescriptor().getProxy();
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bp.getRequestContext();
requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", 120000); // Timeout in millis
requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 120000); // Timeout in millis
```

Any idea why this would not work?

FYI ive also tried the method of using the ibm-ws-bnd file to have Liberty override the timeout settings but this proved even more difficult as it was impossible to discover where they wanted me to place the @WebServiceRef annotation on the *code generated* client.  The fact that the client is code generated removes my complete understanding of how it works without great effort on my part, and I do not have that kind of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the way i set endpoint, basic-auth and timeout. this code only differs from yours in the way you get the instance of the "service".

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

public void foo(Object service) {
    if (service instanceof BindingProvider) {
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)service;
        Map<String, Object> ctx = bp.getRequestContext();
        ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, new URL("http://localhost/url-to-endpoint"));
        ctx.put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ctx.put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 60000);
        ctx.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "auth_user");
        ctx.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "auth_password");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it appears you are calling the JASXWSProperties from com.sun.xml.ws.developer, which i am not doing.  Let me try that.  Why oh why are there so many differing answers to what seems like should be very straight forward?

Comment: I actually do not  have the com.sun.xml.ws package available, I also dont have the javax.xml.ws.client package either which seems to be related to jaxws-rt.jar - this jar file was missing from my SE Java7.079 Oracle download.  I am at a loss.

Comment: you are right my JAXWSProperties comes from jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar. But the  value of the Constants are the same you set directly.
==> public static final String CONNECT_TIMEOUT =
        "com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout";
==> public static final String REQUEST_TIMEOUT =
        "com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout";

Comment: jaxws-rt is an external dependency. see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt

Comment: okay - interesting that it would be an external dependency.  So I have included that jar but the setting is still not being respected.  Its possible I am not casting the right object to the BindingProvider.  I have generated this client using the wsimport code generator tool that comes with eclipse.  the class referenced above is the class I call to call the webservice and the getProxy is returning the SEI interface class

Comment: maybe you are right. my code creates an instance of a generated class which extends "javax.xml.ws.Service". this class has a method like "getXXXPort()" or "getXXXSoapXX". This method exists without any parameter and with a single parameter called "WebServiceFeature... features". this method is also annotated by "@WebEndpoint". please have a look

Comment: Ok so you are right - i am now doing it the exact same way as you are, ive included the jaxws-rt.jar in my WAR's lib file, ive made sure i was casting the right object to BindingProvider and I am setting the timeouts via the requestContext.  Yet still its not respected.  after it calls a long running webservice method, it times out after 60 seconds every time without fail.

Comment: interesting, on startup i am getting a ton of these types of errors:

[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxws-api.jar can not be found in jar file file:/C:/IBM/liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer_2/apps/eNC3ExtWeb_EAR.ear/eNC3ExtWeb_WAR.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.2.5.jar or its parent.